# PHP recursive function Bad Gateway

Tags: php, function, loops, recursion, infinite

I have 2 function in a Class, one is a recursive function.

```
public static function _itemsByParent($categories, $parentId) {
    $out = array();
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        if(empty($category['parent']) && $parentId == 0)
            $out[] = $category;
        elseif($category['parent'] == $parentId)
            $out[] = $category;
    }
    return (empty($out) ? false : $out);
}

public static function loopOnLevels($input, $parent=0) {
    $categories = self::_itemsByParent($input, $parent);
    $out = null;
    if($categories !== false) {
        $i = 0;
        $out = '<ul>';
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $out .= '<li>'.$category['name_hu'];
            $childs = self::loopOnLevels($input, $category['category_id']);
            if($childs !== false) {
                $out .= $childs;
            }
            $out .= '</li>';
            $i++;
        }
        $out .= '</ul>';
    }
    return (empty($out) ? false : $out);
}
```

I pass a simple array and parent is null at start:

```
$o = self::loopOnLevels($categoriesTransformed, 0);
```

My array looks like: http://screencloud.net/v/10sq
....

Why I get 502 Bad Gateway.
Maybe infinite loop? But why?

Comment: Infinite loop yes, run from recursion like from the devil

Comment: Your data appears to be linear, not arbitrarily nested and branched.  If I'm right about this, then you could just iterate over the data without recursion.  Recursion is all well and good, but if iteration will work it's what you should do.

Comment: "Bad Gateway" isn't really what you'd expect from a stack overflow.  Try deleting your browser cache; sometimes that helps with a 502 error.

Comment: So what should i do if i want to process all data in the array parent to children? I need to go through and get parent_id, root_parent, id, etc. Its 3 or 4 level deep.
No its not cache.

Comment: Maybe give a sample of the desired output, showing how lists get nested, etc.  It's not easy to see what you're trying to do.